# Calculate the limit of $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I'm stucked at calculation this limit. Using $Z_n =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ I could rewrite my series as $Z_{2n} - Z_n$ but I couldn't go any further since harmonic series diverges and I wasn't able to calculate the sum.

Comment: I think the term in your sum should be $\dfrac{1}{N+n}$? And you meant $Z_N = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: What does $Z_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ mean? The right hand side does not depend on $n$, it is actually $\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer you're right edits done